# Java swing application causes a leak of pixmaps in X server

Tags: java, swing, x11, netbeans-platform

We have the following setup: 
OS: CentOS 8; 
X11: xorg-x11-server 1.17.2-10.el8; 
Netbeans: RELEASE802; 
Java: OpenJDK 8u222; xrender pipeline is enabled; 
GC: Parallel GC.

There is a simple Java Swing Netbeans platform based GUI application. It contains an Image, two labels, textfields and buttons. While running there is nothing to do for it, but waiting for input.
Additionally to that, there is a proprietary software which records the screen and sends every minute ‘ConfigureNotify’ and ‘Expose’ commands to all applications connected to the X server.

On two different computers with identical setup, at different times we observed a problem but couldn’t reproduce it.
The software runs for a long period of time, ~3-4 weeks. Then without a hint, the Java application doesn’t remove every second pixmap allocated in the X server. This leads to an increase of memory used by the X server and finally to its crash.

Pixmaps are created by native code, and they seem to be bound to XRSurfaceData/X11SurfaceData Java instances. These Java instances are freed by the GC when it is necessary. A Disposer.java disposes the corresponding native instances which remove the pixmaps in the X server.

What could be the cause for the pixmap leak?

Comment: Is the java app increasing in memory use?

Comment: We don't know because we have no recordings of the memory usage of the java gui. We assume there was an increase in used memory for the referenced java SurfaceData but not to a critical point. The leaked pixmaps in the X server had the size of the whole java hmi and each used up to ~6.4mb.

Comment: You might try hooking a debugger up to your app to find any memory leaks.